# List Excel Sheet & Chart Tabs

Tags: vba, excel

This lists & hyperlinks, all Sheets then all Charts. What I would like is for the list to be in the order they are found in the workbook; i.e., sheet1, sheet2, chart1, sheet3, chart 2, etc. I have 126 tabs so a manual reorder isn't an option.

I'm sure there is a way to use an IF/OR but I have no idea how to do the THEN.

```
Sub CreateLinksToAll()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim ch As Chart

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Index").Select
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("A2").Select

   For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
     If ActiveSheet.Name <> sh.Name And sh.Visible Then
       ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
       "'" & sh.Name & "'" & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=sh.Name
       ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If
   Next sh

   For Each ch In ActiveWorkbook.Charts
     If ActiveSheet.Name <> ch.Name And ch.Visible Then
       ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
       "'" & ch.Name & "'" & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=ch.Name
       ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
     End If
   Next ch

  Columns("A:A").Font.Size = 12
  Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you notice that the link to cell A1 of a chart sheet doesn't work? A chart sheet doesn't have cells to link to. You can read how to get around this in an ancient tutorial, http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Hyperlinks.html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting all your worksheets first, and then the charts, because you're doing two iterations over each respective collection.

Instead, iterate over the Workbook's `.Sheets` collection.

**Modified from my original answer**: You dont' need any conditional test for Sheet/Chart in this approach.  This is untested but I think it should work, let me know if it doesn't (probably missing a parenthesis somewhere...).

```
Sub Test()

Dim sh As Variant
Dim rng as Range
Dim r as Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set rng = Sheets("Index").Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))
rng.ClearContents
Set rng = rng.Resize(1,1)

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
   r = r + 1
   rng.Cells(r).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
       "'" & sh.Name & "'" & "!A1", TextToDisplay:=sh.Name

Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: David a very good suggestion but it doesn't answer the question :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout they were appearing "out of order" because he was using two loops. I made my original answer in haste but showed how to do it with one loop. I have since revised to avoid the conditional test for Chart/Sheet, since that should not be necessary.

Comment: + 1 This make more sense now :) Sorry. Didn't see your edit else I wouldn't have posted an answer.

Comment: No worries, I think I was editing it while you were commenting :)

Comment: WOW, you guys are Fantastic!
I'll be in the office within the hour and will update the code.
Thank you!

Comment: The code failed with Syntax error for this line:
    rng.Resize (1,1)
If it is commented out, the code only returns one Chart sheet.

Comment: Ooops. Try `Set rng = rng.Resize(1,1)`.

Comment: Sorry for the dely - work is too busy to answer. Technically it  works, meaning it goes through the list, unfortunately, it just keeps updating A2 so I only have one link when it is done.

Comment: Never Mind - I added the Activecell.Offset back and it works like a Champ!

Comment: New twist, how do I exclude hidden sheet/chart tabs?

Comment: You can check `if sh.visible then...` I think that did exclude hidden sheets.

Comment: Thank you. @DavidZemens Works exactly as I needed though I had to make a few changes to your code above:
removed Set rng (did not work) and after rng.ClearContents I added Range("A2").Select
Then under r =r+1 added the If visible statement and finally added ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select Then End IF above Next.

Answer (score 2):

> What I would like is for the list to be in the order they are found in the workbook; i.e., sheet1, sheet2, chart1, sheet3, chart 2, etc

For this use a simple For Loop

```
For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
Next
```

Here I am simply displaying the name of the sheets in the order they are present in the workbook. Simply put your hyperlink code in lieu of that.

**EDIT**

Also You may find [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select) interesting :)

Comment: Thank you. I will be reviewing the link.